# Entity Framework: Can you cascade deletes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an entity who's primary key is a foreign key in other tables in the database

In order to delete a record in this entity I need to first delete all the foreign keys records or the delete will not work

At the moment i have to select all the foeign key records manually and delete them which is a bit of a pain

Is there a way that you can tell the EF to delete all it's references in other tables automatically?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just set `cascade delete` in your database? (I personally don't, but if you want it, then that's the place to do it, generally).

Comment: Good point. I've done that now :) The EF rocks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF does support cascaded deletes. You need to make sure that in the Association element of both the SSDL and CSDL include an OnDelete action for the appropriate end of the association. Once you set the OnDelete action, EF will enforce it for you.

Comment: Right (+1). You also need to have the cascade in your DB.